# Get grammar from ANTLR4 post conversion?

Tags: antlr4

I understand that the way ANTLR4 works it does some conversions on your grammar for you (getting rid of ambiguity, left-factoring, etc) so that you can just focus on writing more human-readable grammars rather than doing conversions by hand so the machine will accept it. Is there any way to export my grammar after ANTLR makes these changes? I'd like to see what changes were made to my grammar.

Comment: The reference release of ANTLR 4 does not perform any left-factoring. The optimized release of ANTLR 4 does perform left-factoring in certain situations, but the intermediate form produced by the more advanced optimizations in this release (in particular, left-factoring and indirect left-recursion elimination) are not expressible in standard ANTLR grammar syntax.

Comment: That's fine if the grammar would not match the standard. I just want to see the final grammar that it is using in my parsers and lexers.

Comment: I'm saying in some cases there is no ANTLR syntax capable of expressing the final form. The important thing is the transformed representation *behaves* add defined in the original.

Comment: This is like asking what the optimized form of a c++ program is. Optimizations are applied at lower levels than the language syntax, so the output wouldn't be what you expect. Your best option is to simply look at the Java code it produced as output.